# Can't update some fields in user profile

Tags: php, mysql

I'm relatively new to PHP and MySQL, I am trying to learn how to create a user profile page that allows users to edit their information. The issue I am having is that some fields do not change, such as the username, email, and contact field. However, I am able to change the name field alone but not with the other fields. I don't get redirected back and no errors pop up, so I am unsure as to how to fix the issue. Below is my code.

```
<?php

include 'db_conn.php';
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
    header("Location:login.php");
}
$select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid = $_SESSION[userid]") or die('query failed');
if(mysqli_num_rows($select) > 0){
    $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Profile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/water.css@2/out/water.css">
</head>
<body>
     <form action="update-profile-check.php" method="post">
        <h2>PROFILE</h2>
        <?php if (isset($_GET['error'])) { ?>
            <p class="error"><?php echo $_GET['error']; ?></p>
        <?php } ?>

          <?php if (isset($_GET['success'])) { ?>
               <p class="success"><?php echo $_GET['success']; ?></p>
          <?php } ?>
          
          <label>User Name</label>
               <input type="text" 
                      name="uname" 
                      placeholder="User Name"
                      value="<?php echo $fetch['username']; ?>"><br>

          <label>Name</label>
               <input type="text" 
                      name="name" 
                      placeholder="Name"
                      value="<?php echo $fetch['name']; ?>"><br>
        
          <label>Email</label>
               <input type="text" 
                      name="email" 
                      placeholder="Email"
                      value="<?php echo $fetch['email']; ?>"><br>

          <label>Contact</label>
               <input type="text" 
                      name="contact" 
                      placeholder="Contact"
                      value="<?php echo $fetch['contact']; ?>"><br>

        <button type="submit">Update Profile</button>
        <a href="profile.php" class="delete-btn">go back</a>
        <a href="change-pw.php" class="delete-btn">change password</a>
        
        
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php

session_start();
include "db_conn.php";

$select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE userid = $_SESSION[userid]") or die('query failed');
if(mysqli_num_rows($select) > 0){
    $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);
}
$oguname = $fetch['username'];
$ogemail = $fetch['email'];
$ogcontact = $fetch['contact'];
$ogname = $fetch['name'];

$userid = $_SESSION["userid"];


if (isset($_POST['uname']) || isset($_POST['name']) || isset($_POST['email']) || isset($_POST['contact'])) {
    
    function validate($data){
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }

    $uname = validate($_POST['uname']);
    $name = validate($_POST['name']);
    $email = validate($_POST['email']);
    $contact = validate($_POST['contact']);
    $user_data = 'uname='. $uname. '&name='. $name. '&email='. $email. '&contact='. $contact;
    
    
    if (empty($uname)) {
        header("Location: update-profile.php?error=User Name is required&$user_data");
        exit();
    }
    else if(empty($name)){
        header("Location: update-profile.php?error=Name is required&$user_data");
        exit();
    }
    
    else if(empty($email)){
        header("Location: update-profile.php?error=Email is required&$user_data");
        exit();
    }
    
    else if(empty($contact)){
        header("Location: update-profile.php?error=Contact is required&$user_data");
        exit();
    }
    
    else if(!preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z-' ]+)$/", $name)){
        header("Location:update-profile.php?error=Name can only contain letters&$user_data");
        exit();
    }
    
    else if (strlen($name) > 51){
        header("Location:update-profile.php?error=Name is too long&$user_data");
        exit();
    }
    
    else if ($oguname !== $_POST['uname']){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$uname' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{2,16}$/", $uname)){
            header("Location: update-profile.php?error=Username can only contain letters (a-z) and numbers (0-9) and must have a minimum of three characters and maximum of 15 characters&$user_data");
            exit();
        }
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            header("Location: update-profile.php?error=That username is already taken&$user_data");
            exit();
        }
    }
    
    else if($ogemail !== $_POST['email']){
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' ";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            header("Location: update-profile.php?error=Invalid Email&$user_data");
            exit();
        }
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
            header("Location: update-profile.php?error=That email has already been used!&$user_data");
            exit();
        }
    }
    
    else if ($ogcontact !== $_POST['contact']){
        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE contact='$contact' ";
        $result3 = mysqli_query($con, $sql3);
        if(!preg_match("/^[89]\d{7}$/", $contact)){
            header("Location: update-profile.php?error=Invalid Phone Number&$user_data");
            exit();
        }
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {
            header("Location: update-profile.php?error=Phone number has already been used&$user_data");
            exit();
        }
    }
    else{
        $sql4= "UPDATE user SET username = ?, email = ?, contact = ?, name = ? WHERE userid = ?; ";
        
        $query = $con->prepare($sql4);
        
        $query->bind_param("ssisi" ,$uname, $email, $contact, $name, $userid);
        
        if ($query -> execute()){
            header("Location: update-profile.php?success=Succesfully updated");
            exit();
        }else {
            header("Location: update-profile.php?error=unknown error occurred&$user_data");
            exit();
            
        }
    }
}
else{
    header("Location:update-profile.php");
    exit();
}
```

I am not sure as to why only the name field is able to be changed but the rest just redirects and changes nothing. Also, I am trying to incorporate more prepared statements to prevent SQL injections later on.

Comment: You don't need `validate()` if you're using a prepared staatement. There's no good reason to use HTML entity encoding in your database.

Comment: Can you be clearer? Are you saying that if you set new values for all 4 fields, it updates the database but only the name field has been changed? Or something else? It wasn't quite obvious. Give us some examples, if it helps. Also...have you done any debugging to try and narrow down the issue?

Comment: @ADyson Sorry for it being unclear, this is my first post. Right now the issue I am having is that only the name field updates in the database. If I were to set new values for anything else such as the username it does not update the database and nothing happens. The problem is that I have no clue what's causing this and I can't see to narrow it down.

Comment: You probably need to do some debugging to narrow it down, like I mentioned. https://www.atatus.com/blog/php-debugging has a simple guide to debugging with php. You might need to comment out the redirect commands temporarily so it's easier to see the outputs

Comment: Thanks I will look at this and try debugging

Comment: @ADyson Well, I think I may have narrowed the problem down a bit more. Whenever I change the username, email or contact field, my code does not execute the else clause with the SQL statement to update into the database. I suspect it may have to do with else if clauses to check whether those fields had been changed but I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: If it doesn't go into the else, which `if` does it go into?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by removing the else statement with the $sql4.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).